# Rails - ActiveAdmin - Filter another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, activeadmin

I use rails 4.2.4, and activeadmin gem.

I have 2 models.

`User model: email:string, password: string`.

User model `has_one` User Detail.

UserDetail is `belongs_to` User, it have `name:string`.

But, I filter name in

```ruby
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  filter :name
end
```

I don't see name field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the appropriate filter for the associated model. You can do this like:

```ruby
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  filter :user_detail_name
end
```

Where `name` is an attribute of `UserDetail` model.

---

**Update:** Forgot to mention that `ActiveAdmin` utilizes [`ransack`](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) for search under the hood. Based on that you can use `ransack`'s syntax to setup your filters. Here are a couple of resources that could prove to be helpful:

- https://www.viget.com/articles/activeadmin-filters-unlocking-the-power-of-ransack
- https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#associations